# How to solve performance GROUP BY issue in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, performance

I'm building a IoT system for home appliance stuff.

My data table has been created as

```
mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE DataM1\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
   Table: DataM1
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `DataM1` (
  `sensor_type` text,
  `sensor_name` text,
  `timestamp` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `data_type` text,
  `massimo` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `minimo` float DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `timestamp_id` (`timestamp`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `super_index_id` (`timestamp`,`sensor_name`(11),`data_type`(11)) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

and the query is

```
SELECT 
  sensor_type, sensor_name, timestamp, data_type, 
  MAX(massimo) as massimo, MIN(minimo) as minimo 
FROM DataM1 
  WHERE timestamp >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR 
  GROUP BY timestamp, sensor_type, sensor_name, data_type;
```

Now, the problem is that when the table reaches 4 million (few days) rows the query takes 50+ seconds.

Edit: EXPLAIN result is as following:

```
           id: 1
    select_type: SIMPLE
          table: DataM1
     partitions: p0,p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6
           type: range
  possible_keys: timestamp_id,super_index_id
            key: timestamp_id
        key_len: 6
            ref: NULL
           rows: 1
       filtered: 100.00
          Extra: Using index condition; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

Edit: a sample row of reply is:

```
*************************** 418037. row ***************************
sensor_type: SEN
sensor_name: SEN_N2
  timestamp: 2016-10-16 17:28:48
  data_type: flow_rate
    massimo: 17533.8
     minimo: 17533.5
```

Edit: I have normalized the values timestamp, sensor_type, sensor_name and data_type and created a _view to facilitate consuming of data:

```
CREATE VIEW `_view` AS (
  select (
    select `vtmp`.`timestamp` from `timestamp` `vtmp` where (`vtmp`.`no` = `pm`.`timestamp`)) AS `timestamp`,(
      select `vtmp`.`sensor_type` from `sensor_type` `vtmp` where (`vtmp`.`no` = `pm`.`sensor_type`)) AS `sensor_type`,(
        select `vtmp`.`sensor_name` from `sensor_name` `vtmp` where (`vtmp`.`no` = `pm`.`sensor_name`)) AS `sensor_name`,(
          select `vtmp`.`data_type` from `data_type` `vtmp` where (`vtmp`.`no` = `pm`.`data_type`)) AS `data_type`,
          `pm`.`massimo` AS `massimo`,
          `pm`.`minimo` AS `minimo` 
          from `datam1` `pm` order by `pm`.`timestamp` desc);
```

Is there a way to speed up with indexing, sharding and/or partitioning?
Or is better to re-think the table separating the information in different tables? If so, could anyone propose his best practice in such a situation?

Comment: You should post the EXPLAIN result. Some other informations like number of rows within last hour would also be helpfull. And maybe some sample data (only few rows) to see, what your data look like.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel here is EXPLAIN result:          id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: DataM1
   partitions: p0,p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6
         type: range
possible_keys: timestamp_id,super_index_id
          key: timestamp_id
      key_len: 6
          ref: NULL
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using index condition; Using temporary; Using filesort

Comment: @PaulSpiegel number of rows within last hour is 60 minutes * 60 seconds * 8 sensors * 4 data types = 115,200

Comment: So your TEXT colums seem to contain only short strings. A fast fix could be to change them to somthing like VARCHAR(100). And create an index according to your GROUP BY clause. You could also try ENUM instead of VARCHAR.

Comment: Why do you need to collect sensor values each second for each sensor for a simple home automation? Can't you simply reduce the amount of data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Do not use "prefix" indexing such as `sensor_name(11)`; it rarely helps and sometimes hurts.
- If you sensor name and type, and data_type can't be more than 255 characters, don't use `TEXT`; instead `VARCHAR(...)` with some realistic limit.
- Normalize sensor name and type, and data_type -- I assume they are repeated a lot.  `ENUM` is a reasonable alternative.
- KEY(timestamp) and KEY(timestamp, ...) are redundant; DROP the former.
- Your table needs a `PRIMARY KEY`.  If no column (or set of columns) is Unique, then use an `AUTO_INCREMENT`.
- Perhaps you don't want to *start* the `GROUP BY` with the exact timestamp.  Maybe truncate to the hour?  For example, `CONCAT(LEFT(timestamp, 13), ':xx')` would yield something like `2016-10-16 20:xx`.
- The main reason the query is taking a long time is that it is outputing 418K rows.  What will you do with that many rows?  I see no `LIMIT`, nor `ORDER BY`.  Will that continue to be the case?
- Partitioning and sharding will not help the speed any.

Those suggestions will help in various ways.  Once you have fixed most of them, we can discuss how to use Summary Tables to get a 10x speedup.

Comment: Thank you Rick, I think your post gave me many point to improve. The `ENUM` is not a viable way, though, as a must-have behavior is to accept new sensors in a plug-and-play way. Have you time to discuss Summary Tables? Have you good reference link?

Comment: New sensors -- Create another table with id and sensor name; "normalize".  Make the id `TINYINT UNSIGNED` (up to 255 in 1 byte) or `SMALLINT UNSIGNED` (up to 65K in 2 bytes).

Comment: Done. I did this: `CREATE TABLE timestamp ( no BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, timestamp datetime NOT NULL UNIQUE, PRIMARY KEY (no))` and later on I `INSERT IGNORE INTO timestamp` before every insert in the DataM1 table. Is it a best practice?

Comment: It would be much simpler to add `UNIQUE(timestamp)` to your existing table.  (And not add that proposed table.)

Comment: I cannot have unique timestamp in the DataM1 table because at same timestamp I can have dozens of (sensor_type, sensor_name, data_type) triplets.

Comment: Can there be two different `sensor_type` or two different `data_type` for one `sensor_name`?  I'm thinking that `UNIQUE(timestamp, sensor_name)` should work.

Comment: Oh, you need to move away from `TEXT` to `VARCHAR(...)` with a _sensible_ length.

Comment: Work through as many of my suggestions as you can, then start a new Question with clean copies of schema, explains, etc.  This thread is getting too tangled up.

Comment: Just edited the original post with a VIEW of the normalized tables. Thank you very much, I'll will iterate over your "unordered" list, indeed.

Answer (score 1):

This answer discusses how to build a **Summary Table**.

```
CREATE TABLE Summary (
    -- The primary key:
    hr DATETIME  NOT NULL  COMMENT "Start of hour",
    sensor_type ...,
    sensor_name ...,
    -- The aggregates being collected:
    num_readings SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    sum_reading FLOAT NOT NULL,  -- (maybe)
    min_reading FLOAT NOT NULL,
    max_reading FLOAT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(hr, sensor_type, sensor_name),
    INDEX(sensor_name, hour)   -- Maybe you want to look up by sensor?
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Every hour, **populate** it with something like

```
INSERT INTO Summary
    (hr, sensor_type, sensor_name, num_readings,
     sum_reading, min_reading, max_reading)
    SELECT
        FROM_UNIXTIME(3600 * (FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP() / 3600) - 1)),   -- start of prev hour
        sensor_type,
        sensor_name,
        COUNT(*),   -- how many readings were taken in the hour.
        SUM(??),  -- maybe this is not practical, since you seem to have pairs of readings
        MAX(massimo),
        MIN(minimo)
    FROM DataM1
    WHERE `timestamp` >= FROM_UNIXTIME(3600 * (FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP() / 3600) - 1))
      AND `timestamp`  < FROM_UNIXTIME(3600 * (FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP() / 3600)));
```

This assumes you are taking readings every, say, minute.
If you are only taking readings once an hour, it would make more sense to summarize to the hour.

More discussion: [*Summary Tables*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/data-warehousing-summary-tables/) .

To be more robust, the summarization INSERT-SELECT may need to be more complex -- what if you miss an hour.  (And other things that can go wrong.)

**Caveat**:  This summary table will be a lot faster than reading from the "Fact" table, but it can only display ranges of time based on whole hours.  If you need "the last 60 minutes", you will need to go the the Fact table.

Another note:  You *should* normalize bulky, repititous, things like `sensor_name` in the Fact, but you *could* (maybe should) **denormalize** when building the Summary table.  (I left out those steps in this example.)

For **fetching** the data for yesterday:

```
SELECT  sensor_type, sensor_name, data_type,
        MAX(massimo) as massimo,
        MIN(minimo) as minimo 
    FROM Summary 
    WHERE timestamp >= CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY 
      AND timestamp  < CURRENT_DATE()
    GROUP BY sensor_type, sensor_name, data_type;
```

For all of June:

```
    WHERE timestamp >= '2016-06-01'
      AND timestamp  < '2016-06-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

Note:  The simple way to get an average is to average the **averages**.  But the mathematically correct way is to sum the sums and divide by the sum of the counts.  Hence my inclusion of `sum_reading` and `num_readings`.  On the other hand, when averaging things like weather readings, it is common to get the average for each day, then average over the days.  I'll leave it to you decide what is 'right'.

Comment: Trying your `insert into Summary` I got this error: `this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`. Should I disable this flag?

Comment: I pulled `timestamp` out of the `SELECT`; it did not belong.  (Caveat:  There could be other errors.)

Answer (score -1):

I think that is such use cases, when you have so much data, maybe the best solution would be to use a noSQL database, and perform some aggregation before storing the data. You could have a look at [Google Big Query](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/) and [Cloud Data Flow](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/)

However, to answer your question I would pre-calculate the data aggregation using the min granularity required for my system (you could calculate the aggregation every 10 min) and then you will be able to perform your query on smaller amount of data.